# How to know when user has deleted a notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm developing an app that download something data from server and make notifications every time when this data is downloaded successfully. But also i need to send a statistic when user has opened a notify or has deleted it. It simple to send if user has opened a notify - just add a boolean key in intent, and in activity just execute "send" code by this key. But what about the another user action - delete the notify. Here goes my problem -  i can't create any intent cause no activity will be created by this action, how i can know when user has deleted a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example:

```
Intent deleteIntent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingDialog = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, deleteIntent,
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
  .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.title))
  .setContentText(context.getString(R.string.content))
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.image)
  .setContentIntent(clickIntent) // executed if clicked
  .setDeleteIntent(deleteIntent) // executed if deleted
  .addAction(R.drawable.action_image, // adds a button 
             context.getString(R.string.do_it), actionIntent);
```

Pending intents could also be `Broadcasts` as well (check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html)).

Cheers!

Comment: thanks, now i've got it fully - i have a service and i'll just add a broadcast receiver in it when i'll call my "send" code

Answer (score 1):

> how i can know when user has deleted a notification?

Use [`setDeleteIntent()` on your `Notification.Builder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setDeleteIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: excuse me for my stupidity, can you give me an example for it? I didn't get - where i should send this intent? To my Activity? but i don't want to show any acvity after that when user has deleted a notification. I just want to execute a "send statistics" code in my Helper.class

Comment: @whizzzkey: A `PendingIntent` can start an activity, send a command to a service, or send a broadcast. In your case, if "send statistics" involves disk or network I/O, sending a command to a `IntentService` that will "send statistics" would seem to be a likely candidate.